# Problems while trying to crawl links inside visted links with scrapy?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

In order to learn scrapy, I am trying to crawl some inner urls from a list of `start_urls`. The problem is that not all elements from `start_urls` have inner `urls` (here I would like to return `NaN`). Thus, how can I return the following 2 column dataframe `(**)`:

```
visited_link, extracted_link
https://www.example1.com, NaN
https://www.example2.com, NaN
https://www.example3.com, https://www.extracted-link3.com
```

So far, I tried to:

In:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class ToySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toy_example"

    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    start_urls = ['https:example1.com',
                  'https:example2.com',
                  'https:example3.com']


    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a")

        lis_ = []

        for l in links:
            item = ToyCrawlerItem()
            item['visited_link'] = response.url
            item['extracted_link'] = l.xpath('@href').extract_first()
            yield item

        lis_.append(item)
        df = pd.DataFrame(lis_)

        print('\n\n\n\n\n', df, '\n\n\n\n\n')

        df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)
```

However, the above code its returning me:

Out:

```
extracted_link,visited_link
https://www.extracted-link.com,https://www.example1.com
```

I tried to manage the `None` issue values with:

```
   if l == None:
                item['visited_link'] = 'NaN'
            else:
                item['visited_link'] = response.url
```

But it is not working, any idea of how to get `(**)`

`*` yes a dataframe, I know that I can do `-o`, but I will do dataframe operations.

**UPDATE**

After reading @rrschmidt answer I tried to:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")

    lis_ = []

    for l in links:

        item = ToyItem()

        if len(l) == 0:
            item['visited_link'] = 'NaN'
        else:
            item['visited_link'] = response.url

        #item['visited_link'] = response.url

        item['extracted_link'] = l.xpath('@href').extract_first()

        yield item

        print('\n\n\n Aqui:\n\n', item, "\n\n\n")

   lis_.append(item)
   df = pd.DataFrame(lis_)

   print('\n\n\n\n\n', df, '\n\n\n\n\n')

   df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)
```

Nevertheless, it still returned me the same wrong output. Could anybody help me to clarify this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there are two problems with your scraper:

1. as `parse` is called for every element in `start_urls` and you are creating and saving a new dataframe for each link, the dataframes you are generating are overwriting each other.

That's why you will always have only one result in your `crawled_table.csv`

Solution for this: create the dataframe only one time and push all items into the same dataframe object.

Then save the dataframe in each `parse` call, just in case the scraper has to stop before finishing.

2. `if l == None:` won't work as `response.xpath` returns an empty list if no matches were found. So doing `if len(l) == 0:` should do

In a gist here's how I would structure the scraper (code not tested!)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class ToySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toy_example"

    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    start_urls = ['https:example1.com',
                  'https:example2.com',
                  'https:example3.com']

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")
        items = []

        if len(links) == 0:
            item = ToyItem()
            # build item with visited_link = NaN here
            item['visited_link'] = response.url
            item['extracted_link'] = 'NaN'
            items.append(item)
        else:
            for l in links:
                item = ToyItem()
                # build the item as you previously did here
                item['visited_link'] = response.url
                item['extracted_link'] = l.xpath('@href').extract_first()
                items.append(item)

        items_df = pd.DataFrame(items)
        self.df = self.df.append(items_df, ignore_index=True)

        print('\n\n\n\n\n', self.df, '\n\n\n\n\n')
        self.df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)

        return items
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to fix the indentation in order to stop overwriting the data frame, but apparently that did not worked out. Also, I tried to do the `len(l)==0` trick and it also did not worked... Could you provide an example of how to do that?...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added a code example to make the structure clear.

Comment: When I leave the `df = pd.DataFrame()` object out of the parse function I get `NameError: name 'df' is not defined` I put it inside the function and checked out the .csv file and its empty... any idea of what to do?

Comment: You're right, had forgotten to add the `self.` as I made the df a class attribute. Now it should work (just can't test without the proper URLs)

Comment: PS: suggest you also have a look at the basics of Python programming while learning scrapy

Comment: yep, df.append returns a new Dataframe that has to be assigned back to self.df. Fixed it. Please post example urls when this is still not working so I can do a quick test run.