# How to extract an url by its title with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a list of links which I am interested in crawl:

```
lis = ['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com', ..., 'https://exampleN.com']
```

In those links have several urls, I would like to extract some specific inner urls. Such urls have this form:

`<a href="https://interesting-linkN.com" target="_blank" title="Url to news"> News JPG </a>`

How can I inspect all the elements of `lis` and return the `lis`'s visited link and just only urls that have as a title `Url to news` in a pandas dataframe?, something like this (**):

```
visited_link, extracted_link
https://www.example1.com, NaN
https://www.example2.com, NaN
https://www.example3.com, https://interesting-linkN.com
```

Note that for elements of `lis` who do not have any `<a href="https://interesting-linkN.com" target="_blank" title="Url to news"> News JPG </a>` I would like to return `NaN`.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383896/problems-while-trying-to-crawl-links-inside-visted-links-with-scrapy) and:

```
def extract_jpg_url(a_link):
    page = requests.get(a_link)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    # here is the problem... not all interesting links have this xpath, how can I select by title?
    #(apparently all the jpg urls have this form: title="Url to news")
    interesting_link = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a/@href")
    if len(interesting_link) == 0:
        return'NaN'
    else:
        return 'image link ', interesting_link
then:

    df['news_link'] = df['urls_from_lis'].apply(extract_jpg_url)
```

However, the latter approach takes too long and not all the elements of `lis` match the given xpath (check the comment) any idea of what can I in order to get (**)?

Comment: Any idea of how to apply multiprocess in the apply?

Comment: Try `soup.find_all('a', href=True)` to extract the links

Comment: I all ready did that... the problem is that there are a lot of links that are trash... that did not worked... I just want the links that has a title `Url to news` @t.m.adam

Comment: How about : `soup.find_all('a', href=True, attrs={"title":"Url to news"})`

Answer (score 1):

This will not return exactly what you want (NaN), but it will give you the general idea of how to make this work simply and efficiently.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import requests

def extract_urls(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    results = soup.findAll('a', {'title': 'Url to news'})
    results = [x['href'] for x in results]
    return (link, results)

links = [
    "https://example1.com",
    "https://example2.com",
    "https://exampleN.com", ]

p = ThreadPool(10)
r = p.map(extract_urls, links)

for url, results in r:
    print(url, results)
```

Comment: This one really helped me. Is there any way of doing it over the pandas data frame with `multiprocessing`?.... I will update the status with another idea I got... thanks!

Comment: I have never used pandas, so I couldn't tell you. Perhaps someone else could lend some insight?